# Is there a power series $\psi(x)$ such that $\frac{1}{p(x)}=\psi(x)$ for any degree of $p(x)$?

Tags: calculus

Let $p(x)=1-\phi_1x-...-\phi_q x^q$. Is there a power series $\psi(x)$ such that
$\frac{1}{p(x)}=\psi(x)$ for any $q \in \mathbb{N}$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Assuming you mean to expand about $x=0$, consider that $p$ has at most $q$ distinct complex roots, and these are different from $0$, so let $r$ be the root of $p$ that is closest to $0$. Then, $1/p$ is analytic on the open ball of radius $r$ centered at the origin, and therefore has a power series that converges to $1/p$ on this set.

Comment: @MichaelLee Thanks for the comment. I know nothing about complex analysis. Does that theorem have a name? Also, is there a formula for the coefficients of the power series?

Comment: If two polynomials $p_1$ and $p_2$ have the same quotient $\frac{1}{p_1}=\psi=\frac{1}{p_2}$, does it not immediately imply that $p_1=p_2$?  That is, the degree cannot be arbitrary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\rho>0$ be small enough so that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty |ϕ_k|ρ^k\le 1.$$ 
This $ρ$ exists as the power series (or polynomial if the coefficient sequence is finite) to the left has value $0$ for $ρ=0$.

Then $1+\sum_{k>0}ϕ_kz^k$ has no roots with $|z|<\rho$.

The coefficients of the formal reciprocal series
$$
1+ψ_1z+ψ_2z^2+\dots=(1+ϕ_1z+ϕ+2z^2+\dots)^{-1}
$$
can be computed via the Cauchy product formula as 
$$
ψ_0=1,\; ψ_1=-ϕ_1,\;ψ_n=-\sum_{k=1}^nϕ_kψ_{n-k}.
$$
To prove convergence of the power series, use this formula to find a bound on its coefficients
$$
|ψ_n|ρ^n\le \sum_{k=1}^n |ϕ_k|ρ^{k}\,|ψ_{n-k}|ρ^{n-k}\le \sum_{k=1}^n |ϕ_k|ρ^{k}\max_{j=0,...,n-1}|ψ_j|ρ^j\le \max_{j=0,...,n-1}|ψ_j|ρ^j
$$
so that by induction for all $k<n$
$$|ψ_n|ρ^n\le\max_{j=0,...,k}|ψ_j|ρ^j\le|ψ_0|=1.$$ 
This gives $ρ$ as a lower bound for the radius of convergence of $1+\sum_{k>0} ψ_kz^k$ as per the Cauchy-Hadamard theorem
$$
R_ψ=\frac1{\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n\;]{ψ_n}}\ge ρ
$$.

Comment: Many thanks LutzL ;)